# MAMP can't establish database connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to save data from a multi-page form into a database. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/) but the connection always fails. I had to change to function from mysql_connect to mysqli_connect as I am running PHP7, so this could be part of the issue. Here is the code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
  if (!empty($_SESSION['post'])){
  if (empty($_POST['address1'])
  || empty($_POST['city'])
  || empty($_POST['pin'])
  || empty($_POST['state'])){
  // Setting error for page 3.
  $_SESSION['error_page3'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
  header("location: finder-step-3.php"); // Redirecting to third page.
  } else {
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
  }
  extract($_SESSION['post']); // Function to extract array.
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
  $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "finder_form"); // Storing values in database.
  $query = mysqli_query($db, "insert into detail (name,email,contact,password,religion,nationality,gender,qualification,experience,address1,address2,city,pin,state) values('$name','$email','$contact','$password','$religion','$nationality','$gender','$qualification','$experience','$address1','$address2','$city','$pin','$state')", $connection);
  if ($query) {
  echo '<p><span id="success">Form Submitted successfully..!!</span></p>';
  } else {
  echo '<p><span>Form Submission Failed..!!</span></p>';
  }
  unset($_SESSION['post']); // Destroying session.
  }
  } else {
  header("location: finder-step-1.php"); // Redirecting to first page.
  }
  } else {
  header("location: finder-step-1.php"); // Redirecting to first page.
  }
  ?>
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**

@Damon Swayn, I have changed it to the below but still receive the form submission failed message:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "finder_form");
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, "insert into detail (name,email,contact,password,religion,nationality,gender,qualification,experience,address1,address2,city,pin,state) values('$name','$email','$contact','$password','$religion','$nationality','$gender','$qualification','$experience','$address1','$address2','$city','$pin','$state')", $connection);
  if ($query) {
  echo '<p><span id="success">Form Submitted successfully..!!</span></p>';
  } else {
  echo '<p><span>Form Submission Failed..!!</span></p>';
  }
```

@lps, I setup the following on a test.php page in the same directory and it connected successfully:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('Could not connect the database : Username or password incorrect');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'finder_form') or die ('No database found');
echo 'Database Connected successfully';
?>
```

**Update 2: Solved**

The changes suggested by Damon Swayn worked, I just had to remove the $connection at the end of the query. Here is the working code:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "finder_form");
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, "insert into detail (name,email,contact,password,religion,nationality,gender,qualification,experience,address1,address2,city,pin,state) values('$name','$email','$contact','$password','$religion','$nationality','$gender','$qualification','$experience','$address1','$address2','$city','$pin','$state')");
  if ($query) {
  echo '<p><span id="success">Form Submitted successfully..!!</span></p>';
  } else {
  echo '<p><span>Form Submission Failed..!!</span></p>';
  }
```

Comment: well first thing to check is if you can connect to the database directly with those credentials.  besides that some info on the errors you're seeing would help troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hi lps, thanks for your help. I have updated my answer to show the database connects successfully on a test file within the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_connect()` can take 4 parameters, the fourth being the database name.

you are using the return value of `mysqli_select_db()` as the connection param for every following call, `mysqli_select_db()` returns a boolean true/false value, try replacing the `$db` param in the following calls after `mysqli_select_db()` with the `$connection` variable.

Comment: Hi Damon, thanks for your help. I have updated my question showing the above changes but I still get a failed message.